# Pandoc convert tables to pipe tables

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Is it possible to convert all tables to pipe_tables in pandoc?
I can convert all tables to grid, but not all tables to pipe.

```
pandoc -t markdown-pipe_tables-simple_tables-multiline_tables
```

Results in all tables in grid.

But when i do

```
pandoc -t markdown-grid_tables-simple_tables-multiline_tables
```

it results all none pipe tables in html tables.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to make sure that your table is a "simple" table. That means it shouldn't contain any linebreaks and the only block level content is Paragraphs (i.e. no lists, code blocks, blockquotes, etc). Then, your command should work. Otherwise, your table is not representable as a pipe table, thus pandoc falls back to HTML.

The relevant code in pandoc is [`isSimple`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Markdown.hs#L558)...

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to convert to markdown tables with the command: `pandoc --to markdown-pipe_tables-simple_tables-multiline_tables-grid_tables`

Hope this is helpful!